# Oracle - Cannot create new FK on existing table

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, oracle11g

I'm convinced I *must* be doing something incredibly stupid, as it can't be this hard to add a new foreign key to an existing table.  However, I'm still stuck.  Here's what I'm doing.

First, I created a new column in `TPM_USER` to store which team a user is on:

```
ALTER TABLE TPM_USER ADD (
  "TEAMID" NUMBER NULL
)
```

This works without errors, and I can query the `TPM_USER` table to see the new column has been added.  Next, I want TEAMID to refer to a row in the already existing `TPM_DEVELOPMENTTEAMS` table.  So I do:

```
ALTER TABLE TPM_USER
    ADD CONSTRAINT TPM_USER_FK1
    FOREIGN KEY(TEAMID)
    REFERENCES TPM_DEVELOPMENTTEAMS(TEAMID)
```

This gives me the error:

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

I've checked both `TEAMID` columns are the same data type (NUMBER) and TEAMID is of course the primary key of the `DEVELOPMENTTEAMS` table.  In fact, here's the schema for `DEVELOPMENTTEAMS`:

```
CREATE TABLE TPMDBO.TPM_DEVELOPMENTTEAMS  ( 
    TEAMID      NUMBER NULL,
    NAME        VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    ISACTIVE    CHAR(1) NULL,
    SORTORDER   NUMBER NULL,
    SHORTNAME   VARCHAR2(100) NULL,
    GROUPID     NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT TPM_DEVELOPMENTTEAMS_PK PRIMARY KEY(TEAMID)
    NOT DEFERRABLE
     DISABLE NOVALIDATE
)
```

I even tried the GUI interface in Aqua Data Studio to add the new constraint as well, so I'm sure I didn't misspell anything.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess this is because the primary key on the TPM_DEVELOPMENTTEAMS table is set to `DISABLE`. Try to enable it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - *Picard/Riker-Style-Double-Facepalm* That was it, thanks!  Too bad the error message isn't "Your foreign key constraint refers to a primary key that is currently disabled." (And no, it was not me that disabled a primary key, this database was designed by drunken spider monkeys)

Comment: like @a_horse_with_no_name said you can check with Enable a Primary Key The syntax for enabling a primary key is: ALTER TABLE table_name enable CONSTRAINT constraint_name; For Example: ALTER TABLE supplier enable CONSTRAINT supplier_pk;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PK is disabled. Enable it with:

```
ALTER TABLE TPM_DEVELOPMENTTEAMS ENABLE CONSTRAINT TPM_DEVELOPMENTTEAMS_PK;
```

BTW, by declaring it PK, you also made `TPM_DEVELOPMENTTEAMS.TEAMID` non-NULL (so there is no purpose for NULL after it).

Answer (score 0):

You can only refer the column(or combination of columns) which are either enabled Primary Key or Unique Key for the same/other table.

If you find your constraint disabled in below query then you cant create Foreign Key for that PK/UK. You should enable it.

```
select constraint_name from dba_constraints
   where constraint_type in ('P','U')
   and status = 'DISABLED'
   and lower(table_name) = lower(:p_table_name);
```